# Error when posting data values in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Whenever I try to post data values in PHP I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Exception' with message
>   'DateTime::__construct() [datetime.--construct]: Failed to parse time string (this
>   wednesday G:i A) at position 16 (:):
>   Unexpected character' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\keypad\end.php:14
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\keypad\end.php(14):
>   DateTime->__construct('this wednesday
>   ...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\keypad\end.php on line
>   14

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/rent.php'); ?>
<?php

// post

$id = $_GET['id'];
$user = $_GET['user'];
$week = $_GET['week'];
$pRent = $_GET['pRent'];
$status = $_GET['status'];
$rentPaid = $_GET['rentPaid'];
$result = $_GET['result'];
$pDate = date("d/m/Y G:i A");
$lDate = new DateTime('this wednesday G:i A');
$cDate = new DateTime('next tuesday G:i A');

// update 

mysql_query("UPDATE rent SET dNo = '$dNo', pdate = '$pDate', pRent = '$result' WHERE rent.id = $id");


// if pRent = 0 then set status to clear, colour to #3C0
if ($pRent == 0 ) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE rent SET status = 'clear', colour = '#3C0' WHERE rent.id = $id");
} 

// if pRent =! 0 but just paid then set status to paid/not clear, colour to #FF0
elseif ($pRent =! 0 ) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE rent SET status = 'paid', colour = '#3C0' WHERE rent.id = $id");
}

// if status = on holiday, then set status to clear, colour to #3C0
elseif ($status == 'awaiting' ) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE rent SET status = 'awaiting', colour = '#09F' WHERE rent.id = $id");
} 

// check all drivers who have/have not paid rent in the past week
elseif ($lDate < $pDate && $cDate > $pDate) {
    //  date is within desired range
    mysql_query("UPDATE rent SET status = 'paid', colour = '#3C0'");
} else {
    // date is not within desired range
    mysql_query("UPDATE rent SET status = 'awaiting', colour = '#09F' WHERE rent.status =! 'not working'");
}
?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the error message is clear enough. `'this wednesday G:i A'` is not something that `DateTime()` understands.

Comment: I'll just add the standard warnings that your code is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection; please check out PDO prepared statements (http://au.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) as a more secure way to run your SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem on line 14, `$lDate = new DateTime('this wednesday G:i A')` is invalid, take a look at [Relative DateTime formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) for a list of valid ones. What you need to do is:

```
 $lDate = new DateTime('this wednesday')
 $lDate->format('G:i A');
```

Just a suggestion, first two lines should be

```
 <?php 
     require_once 'Connections/rent.php';
```

And please consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or another similar library, or at least sanitize your SQL queries.